# Why doesn't all current flow to ground but instead splits into 2 paths (as shown in the schematic)?

Tags: current, passive-networks

[image: RLC circuit]

I've learnt that "current will flow through the path of least resistance," but in this case, current is split between to 2 paths. Why don't all the current sources flow to ground?

if I applied KCL at node a it will be:

-4 - 2 + I_g + I_r = 0
-> I_g + I_r = 6
So why I_g = 4 and I_r = 2 in this case?

Comment: Shrink the short (a) to (GND) into a single (GND) node. Redraw the circuit.

Comment: Current will not take only the single path of least resistance. It will divide itself in order to minimize the losses. Just apply ohms law. On this case, it's down to the switch resistance.

Comment: The current splits nowhere. The 2A flow through the 6 ohm resistor: from the current source down, then right through the 6ohm resistor and up back to the current source. The 4 amps are shorted to ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, currents don't flow to any particular location, instead they establish complete circular flows.   A single-point ground is irrelevant because it lacks a complete circuit.

To understand this circuit, erase the ground, then analyze as usual.

> I've learnt that "current will flow through the path of least resistance,"

Learnt where?

:)

"Path of least resistance" is a widespread physics-misconception; almost completely[1] bogus.  It doesn't appear in science texts, instead it's something repeated in news articles written by non-techies.   As you've discovered above, it's just not true.

It blatantly violates Ohm's law.

How can we stamp out "path of least resistance" and other similar electricity-misconceptions?  These mistakes spread from mind to mind like a rumor, or like a "disease."  They tend to infect little kids before they had a chance to learn any real physics.   (Heh, so how many other similar physics-mistakes do we all believe right this minute?)

Maybe we can fight fire with fire.  Lets replace "path of least resistance" with an improved version.  For example, here are a couple of semi-correct rules for electricity behavior:

- The greater the pressure-difference, the faster the flow.
- Increasing the resistance will decrease the flow.

These are two re-statements of Ohm's law for wires of fixed diameter.  If the wire AWG stays the same, then a higher current is a faster flow of charge.

.

---

[1] ALMOST, because incoming lightning can be diverted from high-resistance paths using grounded conductors.  But lightning is neither electricity nor current; lightning is a progressive avalanche effect; a gas discharge, same as neon signs and Aurora.  Lightning is more like a growing fracture than  an electric current.  Second, if power supplies have high source-impedances, then suddenly attaching low-resistance load can greatly lower their output voltage.  (Obviously that's how lightning rods function.  They rely on a lightning channel having a fairly significant resistance.)

Perhaps the mistake starts with observations of water: the growing end of a new stream will usually take a single path as it grows downhill.  In some cases electric currents act like water.  But since there's is no closed hydraulic circuit present, the growing water-stream is a false and misleading model for electrical behavior.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the "path of least resistance" concept, it has merely been misapplied.  Any path not returning to the current source is a path with *infinite* resistance for current originating there, so it will not be taken, regardless if it is a low resistance *for some other path*.

Comment: *> There is nothing wrong with* @Chris Stratton   Nope, wrong, since English-speakers understand the phrase to mean "the current is a single thing which cannot split, so instead it choses ONLY the path of least resistance, avoiding all other paths."  The wording leads directly to this common mistake.  You'd be correct if instead it read: "paths of lower resistance have a higher current."  Put that way, it doesn't teach youngsters that a current is like a person who, at a branching path, can only take one branch.

Comment: That distinction has nothing to do with the issue in this question, hence it only serves to distract from the what the poster is trying to understand.

Comment: @Chris Stratton Heh, no, the OP clearly has two misconceptions: the idea that currents "choose a path," and also that the current "chooses *just one* path" and should not split.  Both mistakes in reasoning are well known to physics educators.  Misconceptions like these can prevent understanding for years unless removed.  In science teaching, it's never enough to just supply correct information.  Students commonly misunderstand or even reject the correct information, when it conflicts with deeply-believed misconceptions.

Comment: Again, neither one is at issue in this case. You made some good points about things which are, but overemphasis of something which is not at issue here risks distracting from that.

Comment: @Chris Stratton  We could ask OP!  Does he believe that, when current arrives at a branch point, it must somehow know how to split?   Does he believe that, the current always chooses either one path or the other?   (If he believes neither one, then you're right in the above, and I'm just being a distraction.  But if he believes one or both mistakes, then these misconceptions are the cause of his misunderstanding, and they are the reason he posted his question in the first place.)

Comment: What you are still missing is that neither of those mistaken beliefs would yield an analysis differing from the correct one.  All that actually is required here is to understand that current only flows in complete paths.

Comment: Dear Christ and wbeaty, If I had not asked this question, I would have misunderstood about the concept of current. Thanks for all your helps, and this community is so great.
 
From all of the information above, I conclude that:
- Current flows in closed loop. In the example above, 4A current does not flow back because of the infinite resistance of ground. If there's no ground, 4A current will flow in a loop with no resistance.
- Applying Kirchhoff's Current Law at node a: I will have I_r = 2.
Thanks again.

Comment: @wbeaty Finally someone who understands how current is divided!

Answer (score 1):

The current flow looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your diagram, but I'm still wondering why it happens that way. There are other possibilities that 2A current source will flow both through 6ohm and ground or through ground only.

Comment: The 2A amps coming from the current source have to return to the current source. The only path is the 6 ohm resistor. A current can only flow in loop. It does not originate or terminate somewhere.